# Print lines if pattern is not matched

Tags: text-processing, sed, grep

Print lines of `File 1` only if they don't contain patterns specified in `File 2`

Exemple:

```
$ cat File_1
L1  pattern1
L2  pattern     pattern2
L3  pattern3    pattern
L4  pattern4

$ cat File_2
pattern1
pattern2
```

Expected output

```
$cat File_3
L3  pattern3    pattern
L4  pattern4
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `grep`:

```
$ grep -vFf file2 file1
L3  pattern3    pattern
L4  pattern4
```

`-v`, `-F` and `-f` are defined by [POSIX grep](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/grep.html).

Note that the above will also match subpatterns. For example, if you have `pattern` in file2, that will match `pattern1` in file1. To avoid that you can use `-w` (for GNU and BSD grep, maybe others):

```
$ grep -wvFf file2 file1
```